# Removing the SQL tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have [**decided**](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3038) to burninate the [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag by a clear majority (46 to 7 with 750 views):

> - [Let's burninate the SQL tag!](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3038)

It is now time to work out the details.

I have added an answer below to outline the basic process I think we should follow.

Please **add your own thoughts** to this discussion and up vote answer(s) you agree with.

You may also answer to cover other things we could or should do during this process, to make the final outcome as positive for the site as possible.

For example, this is the place to make the case for **any new tags** that you consider worthwhile for the few questions that might have been legitimately tagged [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) in the past. As a reminder, we already have [query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) and [sql-standard](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-standard).

This post will be [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) for at least 14 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Basic process

1. Change the [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) excerpt to state that it should not be used.
2. **Retag questions** that currently have **only** the [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag.

   This is to avoid questions becoming [untagged](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) when [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) is removed.

   There are currently approximately **229** questions ([SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/910473/questions-tagged-only-sql)) that qualify, so we will need to deal with these at a sensible rate over a period of time.

   We will coordinate this effort using a separate meta Q & A and/or chat room.

Once that process is complete, we can move on to:

3. **Burninate** [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql).

   This will remove it from questions that have other tags besides [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql). There are far too many of these for us to do manually, so we will need the assistance of a Community Manager.

...and finally:

4. **Blacklist** [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) to prevent it being recreated.

---

*Note: this answer does **not** propose creating [sql-language](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-language), as in the original discussion post.*

Comment: Shouldn't we blacklist [tag:sql] as step-1 ? (or maybe step-2).

Comment: @MaxVernon As I understand it, a blacklist request will only be considered once burnination is complete. I will check though.

Comment: @MaxVernon I checked. Blacklisting early would have the undesirable side-effect of disallowing edits to questions with the [sql] tag (unless the tag was removed as part of the edit). This would be confusing for people unaware of the tag cleanup effort.

Answer (score 3):

Just to document the option, I think it would be useful to retain a tag for the language for those odd times when someone has a question about some aspect of the language that works across many database-management-systems.

If you agree it would be useful to have a tag for the language, outside of the existing tag, [sql-standard](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-standard), upvote this option for [structured-query-language](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structured-query-language).

Some example questions that have been tagged with [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql), that might be well-served by [structured-query-language](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structured-query-language):

- [Is a SQL query still called a "query" when doing a deletion, update or insertion?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64381/is-a-sql-query-still-called-a-query-when-doing-a-deletion-update-or-insertion)
- [selecting where two columns are in a set](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/selecting-where-two-columns-are-in-a-set)
- [Mathematical equality of two SQL statements](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96865/mathematical-equality-of-two-sql-statements)
- [About "having" in SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187920/about-having-in-sql)
- [SQL Exercises For beginner](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189270/sql-exercises-for-beginner)
- [ANSI SQL for links](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83026/ansi-sql-for-links)

Comment: You’re winning me over. [tag:sql-language] has the big disadvantage that askers will start typing `sql` and select it from the list.

Comment: I remain unconvinced about this tag and have edited the tags on some of the example questions accordingly (as have others). If you want this tag to stick around, you'll also need to give it much better (more concrete) usage guidance than the current *"Use for questions regarding aspects of the Structured Query Language."*

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47392581#47392581