# Please help us delete the SQL tag!

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Continuing the process started in [Let's burninate the SQL tag!](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3038) and [Removing the SQL tag](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3085).

It is time to work our way through questions that have **only** the [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag.

Use the results of [**this SEDE query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/910473/questions-tagged-only-sql) as a list to work from (data refreshed weekly).

- 2018-10-29: **224 questions** tagged only [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql)

Once this is done, we can ask for the remaining [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) tags to be deleted by a Community Manager.

Please **take your time** on each question, and avoid editing **too many too quickly** to avoid flooding the questions home page (when sorted by recently active). It's not necessary to do a block of questions at once - doing one or two now and again will still be helpful.

Please take **all actions necessary** on the whole Q & A page while you are there to maximize the lasting value of the Q & A. This includes:

- Editing the tags to make the question searchable (and remove [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql)!)
- Improving the title and body of the question for readability
- Voting on the question and any answers
- Incorporating relevant details only found in comments
- Flagging comments for removal

We want to **salvage as much content as possible**, so please approach this task with that goal in the front of your mind.

While the primary goal of the exercise is to remove the [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag, bear in mind that many of the questions you encounter may be quite old.

You may come across questions that are **very obviously unsalvageable**. To avoid swamping the close review queue, please **do not vote to close** in these cases. Raise a custom moderator flag, and briefly describe what you think should happen (close/delete) and why. Also mention the SQL tag cleanup process in your flag. In less clear cut cases, vote to close and/or delete as normal.

There is a [**dedicated chat room**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85026/sql-tag-burnination) for general discussion and coordination.

---

While this phase of the process is not concerned with new questions being tagged [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql), a helpful Community Manager has added the following warning to the Ask Question dialog, displayed when adding [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql):

> The `[sql]` tag is deprecated and will be removed soon. To specify the SQL Server database engine, use the `[sql-server]` tag instead. For details, see [meta](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The retagging exercise is now completed!

Huge thanks to everyone that took part.

Burnination of [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) has been requested and will be tracked on [Let's burninate the SQL tag!](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/lets-burninate-the-sql-tag)